# How to prove or disprove that $\sum\frac{1}{1+x^n}$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$\sum\frac{1}{1+x^n}$  is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R^+$ .  Can anyone please give me a hint to solve this ?

Let alone uniform convergence on $\mathbb R^+$ . I can see that the series is not convergent itself when $x=1$.

Comment: Where did you find assertion it is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}^+$ ?

Comment: I am not sure. That is why I want to prove or disprove.

Comment: sani-- But as you noted it diverges when $x=1$ so is not uniformly convergent on positive reals.

Comment: on $(1,+\infty)$ we have, thanks to *Mathematica*. Convergence is not uniform, tho $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{x^n+1}=\frac{2 \psi _x^{(0)}\left(-\frac{i \pi }{\log x}\right)+2 \log (x-1)+\log x+2 i \pi }{2 \log x}$$

Comment: As you said yourself it diverges for $x=1$. So uniform convergence is out the window.